# Каковы могут быть последствия при такой ситауации?

Tags: android

Вопрос глупый :)

Например, я написал приложение, которое будет в своём `BroadcastReceiver` при загрузке устройства выключать его. Тысячи пользователей останутся с кирпичом. Google Play заблокирует приложение? Как он об этом узнает?

Comment: а зачем вам это?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman чего только из-за женщин не сделают!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во-первых, у приложения нет возможности выключить нерутованное устройство программно.

Во-вторых, это не кирпич, квалифицированный пользователь справится с такой ситуацией.

Во-вторых, Гугл узнает об этом достаточно оперативно: в Google Play есть кнопка Report. С большой вероятностью аккаунт разработчика будет заблокирован.

Answer (score 4):

Программно перезагрузить устройство можно только тогда, когда выполнено хотя бы одно из двух условий:

- Устройство рутовано и Вашему приложению предоставлены рут-парва;
- Ваше приложения является [*device administrator*](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#reboot(android.content.ComponentName)).

По-моему мнению, пользователи с рутованными устройствами априори должны осознавать последствия предоставления приложению рут-прав (поэтому ссзб). Ко всему этому, можно предоставить рут-права приложению только лишь *на один раз*. В этом случае, после пары перезагрузок пользователь просто не даст рут-прав и удалит приложение.

Аналогичная ситуация с добавлением приложения в категорию *администраторов устройств*.

По поводу Google Play могу лишь предположить, что после многократных обращений пользователей в службу поддержки, приложение заблокируют (а может быть и даже весь аккаунт). И никто потом даже не будет слушать сказки про то, что это *ошибочное* поведение Вашего приложения.

По поводу кирпича: кирпич – это состояние невозврата, а в приведенной Вами ситуации, проблема решается откатом к предыдущему бэкапу, либо фулл-вайпом.